# How do I set a default value in a MVC .NET dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

So I have a List to display some years (since 2014 to two years after the current one) in my view and it's working great but what I need right now is to set the currentYear option as my default value in the dropdown list. I'm trying with the selected property but no luck, maybe I'm not implementing it right. Thanks in advance.

In my ViewModel I have this:

```
public int SelectedYear { get; set; }
```

View:

```
List<SelectListItem> selectedYear = new List<SelectListItem>();
int currentYear = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
var minYear = 2014;
var maxYear = currentYear + 2;
for (var i = minYear; i <= maxYear; i++)
{
    if (currentYear == i)
    {
        var year = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = i.ToString(),
            Value = i.ToString(),
            Selected = true
        };
        selectedYear.Add(year);
    }
    else
    {
        var year = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = i.ToString(),
            Value = i.ToString(),
            Selected = false
        };
        selectedYear.Add(year);
    }
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedYear, selectedYear, new { @class = "inlined form-control", @style = "width:100%" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedYear, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: You need to set the value of `SelectedYear` to match one of the optionsbefore you pass the model to the view. And your code can simply be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectedYear = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(2014, 3));`

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.98).aspx

in your controller when you make your select list you can give it a default value, the last parameter is the default/selected value

var yearList = new SelectList(GetYears(), "Id", "Name", selectedDate/Year);

Comment: Not sure why OP has accepted this - its wrong. You could set the last parameter to whatever value you wanted to and it would make no difference - its ignored by the `HtmlHelper`. When using `DropDownListFor()` its the value of the property your binding to that determines what is selected (internally the method builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`